# Parse string regex for known keys but leave separator

Tags: javascript, regex, key-value

Ok, So I hit a little bit of a snag trying to make a regex.

Essentially, I want a string like:

```
error=some=new item user=max dateFrom=2013-01-15T05:00:00.000Z dateTo=2013-01-16T05:00:00.000Z
```

to be parsed to read

```
error=some=new item
user=max
dateFrom=2013-01-15T05:00:00.000Z
ateTo=2013-01-16T05:00:00.000Z
```

So I want it to pull known keywords, and ignore other strings that have *=*.

My current regex looks like this:

```
(error|user|dateFrom|dateTo|timeFrom|timeTo|hang)\=[\w\s\f\-\:]+(?![(error|user|dateFrom|dateTo|timeFrom|timeTo|hang)\=])
```

So I'm using known keywords to be used dynamically so I can list them as being know.

How could I write it to include this requirement?

Comment: Include which requirement? Do you want to split the string or just add linebreaks before every known keyword?

Comment: What about `error=user=max`?

Comment: I would think that should break into
`error=
user=max`

separate results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a replace like so:

```
var input = "error=some=new item user=max dateFrom=2013-01-15T05:00:00.000Z dateTo=2013-01-16T05:00:00.000Z";

var result = input.replace(/\s*\b((?:error|user|dateFrom|dateTo|timeFrom|timeTo|hang)=)/g, "\n$1");
result = result.replace(/^\r?\n/, ""); // remove the first line
```

Result:

```
error=some=new item 
user=max 
dateFrom=2013-01-15T05:00:00.000Z 
dateTo=2013-01-16T05:00:00.000Z
```

Comment: Awesome, that takes that headache out of the way for now. I'd like to see if there actually is a regex that can parse this but this absolutely works in javascript, thank you so much

Comment: @user1251624, updated to a regex replace solution. You can do it with match, but it's more complicated. And that JS doesn't support `\G` doesn't help.

Comment: @Qtax: `\G` support can be emulated with `^` and `substring`. If die-die needs it then it is one way to go about it.

Comment: @nhahtdh, yes, and you can implement PCRE in JS too. `\G` wouldn't be required, but it soothes my soul when in need of a "correct" expression, to make sure nothing is ever missed.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to tokenize the string:

```
var tokens = inputString.split(/ (?=[^= ]+=)/);
```

The regex looks for space that is succeeded by (a non-space-non-equal-sign sequence that ends with a `=`), and split at those spaces.

Result:

```
["error=some=new item", "user=max", "dateFrom=2013-01-15T05:00:00.000Z", "dateTo=2013-01-16T05:00:00.000Z"]
```

Using the technique above and adapt your regex from your question:

```
var tokens = inputString.split(/(?=\b(?:error|user|dateFrom|dateTo|timeFrom|timeTo|hang)=)/);
```

This will correctly split the input pointed out by Qtax mentioned in the comment: `"error=user=max foo=bar"`

```
["error=", "user=max foo=bar"]
```

Comment: Wouldn't work as desired for `error=user=max foo=bar`, where `error=` and `user=max foo=bar` are desired.